# Python: replace function not working

Tags: python

```
PUNCTUATION = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''

WHITE_SPACE = ' \t\n\r\v\f'

EXTRANEOUS  = PUNCTUATION + WHITE_SPACE

str = ["HeLlo!!!,","H%I"]
l = []
for s in str:
    for x in EXTRANEOUS:
        sd = s.replace(x,"")
    l.append(sd)
print(l)
```

Hi! My python code is not working for some reason. I'm trying to get rid of any punctuation mark and white space.

Answer (score 2):

Your code wipes out the result of previous replacements.

```
for s in str:
    for x in EXTRANEOUS:
        s = s.replace(x,"")
    l.append(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `re.sub`:

```
import re
str = ["HeLlo!!!,","H%I"]
final_str = [re.sub('\W+', '', i) for i in str]
```

Output:

```
['HeLlo', 'HI']
```

Answer (score 0):

You always use the unmodified version `s` of your strings. Just replace `sd` with `s`:

```
PUNCTUATION = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''

WHITE_SPACE = ' \t\n\r\v\f'

EXTRANEOUS  = PUNCTUATION + WHITE_SPACE

str = ["HeLlo!!!,","H%I"]
l = []
for s in str:
    for x in EXTRANEOUS:
        s = s.replace(x,"")
    l.append(s)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are not storing the output of the `replace()` function in `s`. Just replace `sd = s.replace(x,"")` with `s = s.replace(x,"")` and `l.append(s)`. One more way to remove punctuation is to do like this .

**`Python 2.x`**:

```
import string

stri = ["HeLlo!!!,","H%I"]
l = []
for s in stri:
    l.append(s.translate(None, string.punctuation))
print(l)
```

**`Python 3.x`**

```
import string

stri = ["HeLlo!!!,","H%I"]
l = []
for s in stri:
    l.append(s.translate(str.maketrans("","", string.punctuation)))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['HeLlo', 'HI']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
PUNCTUATION = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''
WHITE_SPACE = ' \t\n\r\v\f'    
EXTRANEOUS = PUNCTUATION + WHITE_SPACE    
str_list = ["HeLlo!!!","H%I"] # this a list
result = []

for s in str_list:
    l = ""
    for x in s:
        if x not in EXTRANEOUS:
            l += x
    result.append(l)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['HeLlo', 'HI']
```